# Error in code. Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS

Tags: sql, syntax-error

I'm trying to run this query but no matter what I do I keep getting this error and I cannot work it out. Any help would be appreciated.

```
select
  CC.ContactID, 

from 
  Client C 
  join Contacts CC on CC.ContactID = C.ContactID 
 where 

        ClientID In (
    
                                  Select 
                                    ClientID,Sum(Total-allocated) as Bal 
                                  from 
                                    Main 
                                  Where 
                                    Total <> Allocated
                                    and NomTypeID < 10 
                                  Group By 
                                    ClientID
                                  HAVING Sum(Total-allocated) > 10
                             )
```

Comment: Please tag the database you are using

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what DB kind you are using (so I also could not test my answer).

But in general when you use `IN` you need the subquery to return only one column.

So the query should be (removed the `Sum(Total-allocated) as Bal`):

```
select
  CC.ContactID, 

from 
  Client C 
  join Contacts CC on CC.ContactID = C.ContactID 
 where 

        ClientID In (
    
                                  Select 
                                    ClientID 
                                  from 
                                    Main 
                                  Where 
                                    Total <> Allocated
                                    and NomTypeID < 10 
                                  Group By 
                                    ClientID
                                  HAVING Sum(Total-allocated) > 10
                             )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query,

```
select
  CC.ContactID from  
Client C 
join Contacts CC on CC.ContactID = C.ContactID 
join (Select ClientID,Sum(Total-allocated) as Bal from Main Where 
Total <> Allocated and NomTypeID < 10 
Group By ClientID HAVING Sum(Total-allocated) > 10)) m
on (C.ClientID = m.ClientID);
```